# How to pass weights when using Sklearn GridSearchCV with Pipeline

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline, cross-validation, grid-search

I am working on a text classification model, and I am using a [`Pipeline`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) coupled with [`GridSearch Cross Validation`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html). Code Snippets below:

```
count_vec=CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1,2),stop_words=Stopwords_X,min_df=0.01)
TFIDF_Transformer=TfidfTransformer(sublinear_tf=True,norm='l2')

my_pipeline=Pipeline([('Count_Vectorizer',count_vec),
                    ('TF_IDF',TFIDF_Transformer),
                    ('MultiNomial_NB',MultinomialNB())])

param_grid={'Count_Vectorizer__ngram_range':[(1,1),(1,2),(2,2)],
               'Count_Vectorizer__stop_words':[Stopwords_X,stopwords],
               'Count_Vectorizer__min_df':[0.001,0.005,0.01],
               'TF_IDF__sublinear_tf':[True,False],
               'TF_IDF__norm':['l2'],
               'TF_IDF__smooth_idf':[True,False],
               'MultiNomial_NB__alpha':[0.2,0.4,0.5,0.6],
               'MultiNomial_NB__fit_prior':[True,False]}

# Grid Search CV with pipeline
model=GridSearchCV(estimator=my_pipeline,param_grid=param_grid,
                   scoring=scoring,cv=4,verbose=1,refit=False)
```

**However**, as the data is highly imbalanced, I want to pass weights to the [`MultinomialNB`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) classifier in the pipeline. I know that I can pass weights to elements within the pipeline (as shown below):

```
model.fit(Data_Labeled['Clean-Merged-Final'], 
          Data_Labeled['Labels'],MultiNomial_NB__sample_weight=weights)
```

**My question is how does this compile without a shape error?** as weights are only passed to the final element (MultiNomial_NB classifier) in the pipeline while CV partitions the X/Y feed entering the pipeline.

Comment: Are you saying you are not getting any error where you should?

Comment: @VivekKumar yes, my understanding is that the fit method partitions the data into 4 folds, keeping one set out everytime, while the weights argument go directly to the classifier at the end of the pipeline, resulting in shape inconsistencies. Or perhaps I am missing something...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GridSearchCV handles the appropriate breaking up of sample_weights according to the cross-validation iterator.

GridSearchCV calls the [`_fit_and_score()`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.19.X/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L346) method internally on the data and passes the indices for the training data. Up until now, the fit_params are for the whole data. Now this function in turn calls the function [`_index_param_value`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0.19.X/sklearn/model_selection/_validation.py#L828), which handles the splitting of the `sample_weight` (or other fit_params)
in this line:

```
     ...
     return safe_indexing(v, indices)
     ...
```

This has been discussed in issues here:

- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/2879
- https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9203